# (Java) Letting a program display every possible combination of hex color codes. Is it possible to sometimes let a string display char and int?

Tags: java, string, integer, hex

I know the title isn't very well asked...sorry.
As you may know, a hex color code can have numbers and characters in it (#ff0000)
I started by writing a little program which lists all possible combinations (16^6) and writes them in
the console. This does work.
Now I wanted to change the background of a j frame to the color that's currently written in the console as a hex code. Java seems to only accepts RGB combinations, so I used
Color col = Color.decode(HexCode)
to get these RGB values, which worked to.
Now I wanted to combine these to "program" as at this point the j frame only displayed one color i place directly in the code
Color col = Color.decode(#ff0000)
which was not my end goal.

I have the hex code positions defined as #abcdef (as ints)
but for the decoding to work sometimes they don't only need to be numbers but characters.
And that's my question, how does one do that ?

This is my code at this point:

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test3 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a,b,c,d,e,f;
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Dima");
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(100,100);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
         for(a=0;a<=15;a++) {
           for(b=0;b<=15;b++) {
             for(c=0;c<=15;c++) {
               for(d=0;d<=15;d++) {
                 for(e=0;e<=15;e++) {
                   for(f=0;f<=15;f++) {
                       
        //Hex Indikator
            System.out.print("#");         
        //Konsolenprint von a              
        if( a == 15 ) {
            System.out.print("f");}else
        if ( a == 14 ) {
            System.out.print("e");}else
        if ( a == 13 ) {
            System.out.print("d");}else
        if ( a == 12 ) {
            System.out.print("c");}else
        if ( a == 11 ) {
            System.out.print("b");}else
        if ( a == 10 ) {
            System.out.print("a");}else{
                System.out.print(a);
            }
      //Konsolenprint von b        
        if( b == 15 ) {
            System.out.print("f");}else
        if ( b == 14 ) {
            System.out.print("e");}else
        if ( b == 13 ) {
            System.out.print("d");}else
        if ( b == 12 ) {
            System.out.print("c");}else
        if ( b == 11 ) {
            System.out.print("b");}else
        if ( b == 10 ) {
            System.out.print("a");}else {
                 System.out.print(b);
            }
      //Konsolenprint von c        
        if( c == 15 ) {
            System.out.print("f");}else
        if ( c == 14 ) {
            System.out.print("e");}else
        if ( c == 13 ) {
            System.out.print("d");}else
        if ( c == 12 ) {
            System.out.print("c");}else
        if ( c == 11 ) {
            System.out.print("b");}else
        if ( c == 10 ) {
            System.out.print("a");}else {
                 System.out.print(c);
            }
      //Konsolenprint von d        
        if( d == 15 ) {
            System.out.print("f");}else
        if ( d == 14 ) {
            System.out.print("e");}else
        if ( d == 13 ) {
            System.out.print("d");}else
        if ( d == 12 ) {
            System.out.print("c");}else
        if ( d == 11 ) {
            System.out.print("b");}else
        if ( d == 10 ) {
            System.out.print("a");}else {
                 System.out.print(d);
            }
      //Konsolenprint von e        
        if( e == 15 ) {
            System.out.print("f");}else
        if ( e == 14 ) {
            System.out.print("e");}else
        if ( e == 13 ) {
            System.out.print("d");}else
        if ( e == 12 ) {
            System.out.print("c");}else
        if ( e == 11 ) {
            System.out.print("b");}else
        if ( e == 10 ) {
            System.out.print("a");}else {
                 System.out.print(e);
            }  
      //Konsolenprint von f        
        if( f == 15 ) {
            System.out.println("f");}else
        if ( f == 14 ) {
            System.out.println("e");}else
        if ( f == 13 ) {
            System.out.println("d");}else
        if ( f == 12 ) {
            System.out.println("c");}else
        if ( f == 11 ) {
            System.out.println("b");}else
        if ( f == 10 ) {
            System.out.println("a");}else {
                 System.out.println(f);
            }    
        String ColorCode = "#";
         
        
        //System.out.println(" Hier ist das Problem : " + ColorCode);
                 
           //Color col = Color.decode(HexCode);
           //jf.getContentPane().setBackground(col);
                
            }
           } 
          }
         }
        }       
       }
      }
     }
```

I hope you understand my problem, it is a little difficult to describe it for me :/

I tried making Strings refer to other strings and tried to set strings
in the if functions to a character, but it didn't work out.

Comment: You can list them all in a loop from 0 to that number. Just output the number as hex with with `Integer.toString(n, 16);`

Comment: Are you trying create a small Swing app which cycles through all possible background colors for the JFrame's contentPane? If so, why do you need to generate hex codes first? Just iterate from 0 -> 16^6 (16777216), and decompose the value into r, g, b values: ```int blue = i >> 0 & 0xFF; int red = i >> 16 & 0xFF; int green = i >> 8 & 0xFF; ... new Color(red, green, blue);``` Do the iteration in a ```SwingWorker.doInBackground```.

Comment: Or in Swing `Timer`. Cancel if color == 0xFFFFFF `comp.setBackground(new Color(color++));` Timer at 500ms ≈ 100 days to cycle through

Comment: I suggest rethinking how you look up the hex value of each digit. The if-else-if approach is far too much repetitive code -- easy to make a mistake in, hard to debug. (Yes, it may be working for you now, but it's not good.) With those if-else-if blocks, you are doing a lookup which has a one-to-one correspondence: base10 int -> base16 int. Hint: take the first 5 letters of "arrange", add a "y", and that's the data structure you are looking for as the lookup.

Comment: Finally, isn't the result of the nested for loops the same as a single loop ```for (int I = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 24); I++) {...}```? (2^24 == 16^6) Is there some requirement to generate each digit?

Comment: Sorry for not answering...
g00se: I will test your suggesting thanks for your help
pfurbacher: no, the displaying of colors through a j frame is only for testing purposes. I wanted to test if I can cycle through all variations from #000000 to #ffffff.
I will try to generate the hex values in another way, there is no "real" requirement to generate the code besides that #000000 the smallest value should be the start and counting upwards so #ffffff is the end.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: No problem. Yes your loop can be just `for(int i = 0;i <= 0xFFFFFF;i++) { Color c = new Color(i); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

This works, I will try g00se idea later, but this works fine:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        for (int red = 0; red <= 255; red++) {
            for (int green = 0; green <= 255; green++) {
                for (int blue = 0; blue <= 255; blue++) {
                    String redHex = String.format("%02x", red);
                    String greenHex = String.format("%02x", green);
                    String blueHex = String.format("%02x", blue);

                    String colorCode = "#" + redHex + greenHex + blueHex;
                    System.out.println(colorCode);
                    
                    Color col = Color.decode(colorCode);
                    jf.getContentPane().setBackground(col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and ideas :)

Comment: I don't get g00se idea to work. Not at the moment, as long as the now renewed code makes no problems this issue is resolved. If there are problems in the future, I will correct my mistakes :)